# Firesharp API How i can get new values?

Tags: c#, firebase, winforms, firebase-realtime-database

I have some questions about C# Firesharp API. I need to listen Database for new values. I mean when new values added to Database i should get that values immediately. I tried to use Timer but Timer was working so slowly and it wasnt like what i need. Is there methods to use solve my problem? I tried OnAsync method from C# Firesharp API. But it just was logging old values to me.

Here is what i tried:

```
IFirebaseConfig firebaseConfig = new FirebaseConfig
{
    AuthSecret = "",
    BasePath = ""
};
FirebaseClient client = new FirebaseClient(firebaseConfig);
EventStreamResponse response = await client.OnAsync("Test", Degistiginde);

private void Degistiginde(object sender, ValueAddedEventArgs args, object context)
{
    MessageBox.Show(args.Data);
}
```

Comment: Adding a listener to `OnAsync` should initially give you the current value of the node, and then also get called whenever the value in the database changes. Are you saying it is not doing the latter?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen No, unfortunately it is not doing anything. When i used that method,
It just logging the nodes for one time and stopping. But i was trying to add values from on  Firebase Console. Should be added on a Application?

Comment: Neh, that's not needed. It should reflect both. I'm not sure what could be causing it not to. Hopefully somebody else spots the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I hope someone tells the problem.

Answer (score 3):

after much research I have found a method that works.
Apparently the sample code on the project's github page doesn't work, I guess it's out of date.

For it to work you have to separate the update cases, like this:

```
EventStreamResponse response = await _client.OnAsync("yourfirebaseassetreference", added: (s, args, context) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
        },
        changed: (s, args, context) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
         },
         removed: (s, args, context) =>
         {
            Console.WriteLine(args);
         });
```

Greetings.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It works that way!